# Floating issues in Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

So everything appears fine for me on any browser or computer I have tried but my client has been having issues with the page. I have been able to trace his issues based on screenshots to the absence of the float:right style being added the element listed below. When I turn off the float in my browsers inspector I can replicate his problem perfectly. With that said, I don't know how to fix it because the fix is already in place.

```
#archive, #container .sale ul.products {
    width: 768px;
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    float: right;
}
```

This is has been occuring for weeks and is definitely not cache related

Comment: have you tried validating your code? http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fbolivares.com%2Fproduct-category%2Faccessory%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 I get 25 errors, among which duplicate ID's. Worth fixing those first as they may cause 'strange' behaviours in some browsers...

Comment: What screenshots are you referring to?  I would recommend first getting the exact OS/Browser/Version from your client to replicate the problem (as you mentioned, everything seems to look fine).